# android php login and mysql requests

Tags: php, android

what is the best / common way to authenticate my android app on my mysql / php server backend?

my idea is to send first user and pass (SSL), if the informations are correct generate a String on the backend, send the authenticated string back to the android device and store the string in the mysql user table. for every new php / mysql query i send the request data with the authentication string and check if the string exist in the user db - if the auth string is correct i'll send back the result data.

is this a common and secure way?

thanks
-markus

Comment: you can use `UUID` from device authentication

Comment: In general, your idea is correct and your string is named token. Which php server are you using?

Comment: thx! apache tomcat 7. the token needs to be generated by the backend, correct?